# What are common words called, such as "the", "and", "to" etc?

Tags: synonyms, common-word

I remember there was a fancier term for these common words, that search engines ignore.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: I have not closevoted, but a review of the [help] on writing good questions might be in order. For example, editing to describe why you need this word and how you plan to use it would help narrow down options. Also, it's good practice to indicate what research have you already attempted in the matter, and perhaps some possibilities that you have rejected, and why. If it looks like a questioner has not put any effort into the question, potential answerers will not want to put any effort into it, either.

Comment: This question is unclear. 'Common' can be a number of things. Can you clarify?

Comment: @choster: The questioner appears to not have put any effort because they have *answered the question*. I simply remembered the correct term a few minutes after I asked the question, and left a detailed answer. Should I go back to the question and belabor the point showing how I've racked my brains trying to remember the name of the word?

Answer (score 2):

They're called [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words):

> In computing, stop words are words which are filtered out before or after processing of natural language data (text).[1] Though stop words usually refer to the most common words in a language, there is no single universal list of stop words used by all natural language processing tools, and indeed not all tools even use such a list. Some tools specifically avoid removing these stop words to support phrase search.